# Where can I buy a 220v to 110v transformer in Buenos Aires at a reasonable price?

Tags: shopping, argentina, buenos-aires, power

The house I'm renting has some 110v audio equipment that I'd like to use and the transformer that they have seems to be fried. I'm looking for a shop where I can buy a transformer at a reasonable price. If it's close to Subte Ministro Carranza that'd be a bonus, but I'm willing to travel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think many electric hardware stores have these items, walk a couple of streets in the center and I guess you find a couple. Otherwise the feria (market) might also have stands that sell that sort of stuff.

If all fails, here I have a link to MercadoLibre, the ebay of latin america, they have plenty of these items for sale in the capital: [transformador 220v a 110v](http://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/transformador-220v-a-110v)

Comment: Ikku is right, you can also go to big supermarkets like Disco, Coto ,Carrefour or Jumbo (look for the really big ones) and they will have it. Also there is a big Easy Store where you can definitely get it. https://www.easy.com.ar/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/es/easyar